# how to stop onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to stop the default close event with,
`event.stopPropogation()` and also `event.preventDefault()` But, it doesn't help me to stop the process.

Could any of you know how to stop this default close event?

Is it possible to listen for browser click event?

Comment: What exectly do you expect of preventing this event? If it is preventing the page from being changed, then it can be a security problem: any page could be designed the way user can't leave it.

Comment: OK. Is it possible to listen for browser click event?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "browser click event" in this context.

Comment: Maybe you sould describe the context of your question and what behavior do you want to achieve.

Comment: we can listen for window click event right? Similarly is there any option to listen the browser close button click?

Comment: No way. All your page scripts are related to your document - read HTML - and not the browser as a program.

Comment: Please don't add a signature to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot programmatically stop the user from closing the page, for obvious reasons. The only way is to have the browser ask a confirmation question from the user (by returning the close question as a string from the event).

Comment: Is it possible to listen for browser click event?